# Eliminate items of a nested list, inside a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a nested list inside a nested dictionary. Those are lists when they have more than 1 value. I would like to only keep the first item of the list, and transform it into a single string.

Current list of dicts:

```
list_dicts= [{'id': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],'text': 'hello1'}, 
             {'id': 'data20', 'text': 'hello2'}]
```

As you can see some `'id'` values are lists, but I would like to transform the list into what the second item of `list_dicts` looks like.
Desired output:

```
list_dicts2= [{'id': 'data1','text': 'hello1'}, 
             {'id': 'data20', 'text': 'hello2'}]
```

My code attempt:

```
for d in list_dicts:
    for v in d['id']:
        if v>0:  #does not work becomes some 'v' are a single string, not a list
           # v.pop() ..???
```

Comment: I didn't understand in which case you want to keep the 2nd element of which list, can you exmplain?

Comment: and you just drop `data2` and `data3`?

Comment: look at the current list of dicts and the desired output, and compare. The second item in list_dicts is different to the second item in list_dicts2. I want it to be like in list_dicts2.

Comment: Ok then the solutions provided are what you need

Comment: indeed they are :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save keep only the first element in case of lists as `id` values, you can do:

```
list_dicts= [{'id': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],'text': 'hello1'}, 
             {'id': 'data20', 'text': 'hello2'}] 

for d in list_dicts:
    if isinstance(d['id'], list):
        d['id'] = d['id'][0]
            
print(list_dicts)
```

The output will be:

```
[{'id': 'data1', 'text': 'hello1'}, {'id': 'data20', 'text': 'hello2'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try those comprehensions:

```
list_dicts = [{k:(v[0] if isinstance( v, list ) else v) for k,v in dict_item.items() } for dict_item in list_dicts]
```

Note that it would do so to any key values pairs that have list..

Answer (score 1):

You can do assignment instead of "pop"

```
  for d in list_dicts:
        if isinstance(d['id'], list):
            d['id'] = d['id'][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i_l = [{'id': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],'text': 'hello1'}, 
             {'id': 'data20', 'text': 'hello2'}] 

o_l = []
for i in i_l:
    d = {}
    for k, v in i.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            d[k] = v[0]
        else:
            d[k] = v
    o_l.append(d)
    
        
o_l
```